# basic about "using" construct

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If I use "using" construct, I know that the object gets automatically disposed.  What happens if a statement inside an "using" construct raises an exception.  Is the "using" object still disposed?  If so, when?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `using` block is converted - by the compiler - to this:

```
DisposableType yourObj = new DisposableType();
try
{
    //contents of using block
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)yourObj).Dispose();
}
```

By putting the `Dispose()` call in the `finally` block, it ensures `Dispose` is **always** called - unless of course the exception occurs at the instantiation site, since that happens outside the `try`.

It is important to remember that `using` is not a special kind of operator or construct - it's just something the compiler replaces with something else that's slightly more obtuse.

Comment: It's also important to note that, as your example illustrates, if the call to DisposableType() throws an exception, Dispose() won't be called; any resources allocated there prior to the exception won't be released.

Comment: There's a `null`-test in the `finally` block as well.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what it says in the manual, of course. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[This article explains it nicely.](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx)

> Internally, this bad boy generates a try / finally around the object being allocated and calls Dispose() for you.  It saves you the hassle of manually creating the try / finally block and calling Dispose().

Answer (score 2):

Actually Using block is Equivalent to try - finally block, Which ensures that finally will always execute e.g.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Command", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Equals to

```
SqlConnection con =  null;
SqlCommand cmd = null;

try
{
    con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Command", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    if (null != cmd);
        cmd.Dispose();
    if (null != con)
        con.Dispose();
}
```